# Amazon AWS Workspaces Subnet Control

Tags: amazon-web-services, workspace, subnet, vpc

I am having a couple of issues with a VPC/Simple AD/Workspaces environment that I created.

Based on Amazon's documentation, I built a VPC, Simple AD and Workspaces environment. The VPC data flow is listed below in the diagram.  The private subnets are flowing through the NAT GW (project-nat-public1-us-east-1a) and the public subnets are flowing through the Internet Gateway (project-igw).

The Simple AD configuration contains one public and one private subnet.

Simple AD Config
project-subnet-public1-us-east-1a - 10.0.0.0/20
project-subnet-private2-us-east-1b - 10.0.144.0/20

Subnets
subnet-0377598c8d199b786 / project-subnet-public1-us-east-1a    - 10.0.0.0/20
subnet-0333598c8d199b444 / project-subnet-private1-us-east-1a - 10.0.128.0/20
subnet-0abdc358198a8767e / project-subnet-private2-us-east-1b - 10.0.144.0/20
subnet-0fa59834ad498af13 / project-subnet-public2-us-east-1b    - 10.0.16.0/20

[image]

Problem:

1. The first issue is I cannot seem to control which subnet within the Simple AD configuration a newly created Workspace lands.  It will be part of either 10.0.0.0/20 or 10.0.144.0/20.  Is there a way to control which subnet the Workspaces system will fall into.  I am trying to get all Workspaces to be part of 10.0.144.0/20.
2. The second issue is Internet access is NOT available when a Workspace system lands in the public subnet 10.0.0.0/20, which flows through the Internet Gateway (project-igw). I created an EC2 and put it in this subnet.  I was able to get Internet access by using a security group and providing the appropriate firewall rules.  I tried to enable Internet access through the Simple AD configuration and add a security group, but that didn't work either.

Has anybody had these issues and resolved it?